# Laravel URL::asset for 404's view

Tags: laravel, url, view, http-status-code-404, assets

I'm embellishing Laravel's 404 page (ressources/views/erros/404.blade.php). But, I can't load my CSS and JS files, which are, in my public folder.

Actually, Laravel is returning me **localhost/css/bootstrap.css** when it should return me localhost/myproject/public/css/bootstrap.css with **{{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}**. While it's returning me localhost/myproject/public/css/bootstrap.css when I'm on another view (with the same code: {{ URL::asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}) on my home page wich is perfectly working.

By the way, I'm using Laravel 5.3.

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: use <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}"> instead

Comment: <link href="{{asset('css/bootstrap.css')}}">  doesn't change anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure your webserver so the root of domain (localhost) points to public/ -folder.

Vagrant-solution like Homestead would probably make setting up the development-environment easier for you.